# Stata: Correctly import massive delimited text file (from R) with multi line content and row numbers

Tags: r, csv, text, import, stata

I fail to import a dataset which I exported from R into Stata 14.1. It contains comments that users wrote to each other. It has the following structure:

```
    "project_id" "project_title" "project_owner_user_id" "comment_user_user_id" "comment_date" "comment_censored" "censored_reason" "comment_content"
"1" 36 "Vending Machine" "u1" "u1" "2011-06-24 04:03:57" 0 "" "SNOTty vending machine I built for a display model."
"2" 36 "Vending Machine" "u1" "u1" "2011-07-06 01:41:30" 0 "" " Can't wait to share it!  Some technical difficulties finding/getting to the image online.  Stay tuned."
"3" 41 "Animated Stock Car" "u2" "u2" "2011-07-12 00:25:40" 0 "" "Stockcars were an American invention, introduced in the mid 1800s as a way to transport livestock of various kinds. Thousands were used in great blocks by various western railroads to collect cattle from railheads in frontier towns such as Amarillo and Dodge City, and transport them to the great meat packing cities of Chicago and Kansas City, where the slaughterhouses awaited. 

They were also used for horse transport, as this one is."
"4" 40 "Pacific Electric Hollywood Car Trolley" "u3" "u2" "2011-07-12 00:51:29" 0 "" "What kind of trucks did you have in mind for this? My streetcar model uses standard 9V trucks"
"5" 43 "WeCan - 6 times expansion of WeDo -" "u4" "u4" "2011-07-12 23:59:47" 0 "" "Expansion of present WeDo, it is WeCan.
we can use 12 ports of interaction ports."
"6" 44 "WeMust - pneumatic step from WeDo -" "u4" "u4" "2011-07-13 00:07:09" 0 "" "Automatic pneumatic cylinder controller using USB port."
```

For some reason Stata fails to detect the correct number of variables (in the first line) and adds additional variables:
[image]

Additionally the contents of the variables are all shifted to the right, because Stata fails to recognize the line numbers at the beginning of the lines. If i manually edit the text file and add an additional variable "line_number" in the first line of the file, this issue is resolved.

To make things worse the file has 652569 observations and contains entries in several languages including Mandarin etc.

The file is UTF-8 encoded. How can I correctly import this file in Stata?

In contrastR does a great job and imports it correctly with a simple oneliner:

```
X <- read.table ("x.txt")
```

However my collaborator wants to use Stata. Thanks for your help!

PS: Link to the textfile for reproduction:
http://www25.zippyshare.com/v/UKOExjU3/file.html

Comment: As your question shows, Stata is minded to treat `" "` as string delimiters and so to split a record accordingly into different variables. If you want to override that, you need different delimiters or to insist that everything is read in as one `strL` variable.

Comment: How to insist that everything is read in as one strL variable? Unfortunately I am not really proficient in Stata. Thank you!

Why does it distribute "this one is" in thee variables? There are only ordinary spaces inside.

Comment: Difficult to say without a reproducible example. Sometimes characters other than spaces have side-effects.

Comment: Please show how you are exporting the data from R, specifically `write.table()` command.

Comment: @NickCox hmm I provided a reproducible example?

Comment: @Parfait
I import the original data in r with:
`X <- read.csv ("data.csv", header = T)`
then get rid of around 200k problematic observations and then export it with:
`write.table(X, file = ("data.txt")`

Comment: Why aren't you using `write.csv()` and maintain same structure as input: comma-separated?

Comment: @Parfait I tried that too with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Stata's [insheet](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?insheet) command, specifying the space delimiter. Do note: this is a coded solution to be used in .do file or command window and not via Stata's GUI menu per your screenshot:

```
clear
insheet using "path/to/data.txt", delimiter(" ")
```

**Initial Output**

Below uses your linked file and you will notice an unnamed *v9* column outputs. And in dataset everything is shifted to the right. The reason being is that in R you are exporting the *row.names* which do not have column headers and so Stata reads in all named/unnamed columns. So, Stata's *project_id* aligns to R's *row.names* (1,2,3,4,5), Stata's *project_title* for R's *project_id*, and so on.

```
Contains data
  obs:             6                          
 vars:             9                          
 size:         1,878 (99.9% of memory free)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
project_id      byte   %8.0g                  
project_title   byte   %8.0g                  
project_owner~d str38  %38s                   
comment_user_~d str2   %9s                    
comment_date    str2   %9s                    
comment_censo~d str19  %19s                   
censored_reason byte   %8.0g                  
comment_content byte   %8.0g                  
v9              str244 %244s                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  
     Note:  dataset has changed since last saved
```

**Resolution**

To resolve above column misalignment, for your text output in R do not output *row.names*:

```r
write.table(X, file = ("data.txt"), row.names = FALSE)
```

And if you do want to keep an ID, add it as a new, named column to include in export:

```r
X$ID <- row.names(X)
```

---

Even better is using a consistent delimiter like comma  or tab using the *sep* argument. In R, the command `write.csv(...)` is actually a convenient wrapper for `write.table(..., sep = ",")`:

```r
write.csv(X, file = ("data.txt"), row.names = FALSE)

write.table(X, file = ("data.txt"), row.names = FALSE, sep="\t")
```

Then in Stata, specify with `insheet` options being *comma* or *tab*:

```
insheet using "/path/to/data.txt", comma

insheet using "/path/to/data.txt", tab
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works nicely for the sample I provided. I also tinkered around with exports skipping row.names but did not get it to run. Now I tried to run the code on the full data set containing 652569 observations but I get only 383650:
http://imgur.com/a/EiilF

If I enter describe stata comes with this output:

`Contains data
  obs:       383,650                          
 vars:             9                          
 size: 1,675,399,550     `

Comment: `
project_id      str1745 %1745s                
project_title   str293  %293s                 
project_owner~d str32   %32s                  
comment_user_~d str32   %32s                  
comment_date    str19   %19s                  
comment_censo~d byte    %8.0g                 
censored_reason str196  %196s                 
comment_content str2045 %2045s                
rownames        long    %12.0g                rowNames
`

Any idea why this could happen? Unfortunately I cannot provide the full dataset.

Comment: interestingly 
`import delimited "X_withRownames.txt", delimiter(tab) bindquote(strict) varnames(1) stripquote(yes) case(preserve) encoding(UTF-8)`
now works too and I end up having variables with 383,714 observations

Comment: should I ask a new question on stackoverflow now for this one?

Comment: Though all records do not import, are columns aligned properly, specifying correct delimiter? If so, possibly memory constraints are the issue as you have a large text field among other fields for 650,000+ records, a pretty large file. Try adjusting [memory](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?set_memory) prior to import.

Comment: I tried `set max_memory 45g` before running the command.. `insheet` now leads to `(9 vars, 383,650 obs)`, increasing it further did not change anything.

Comment: Interesting. Locate that specific record and see if there is something unusual about it. Post it and the one right after. When importing text file with `read.table()` into R, same cut off?

Comment: No, exporting and reimporting the file in R works just fine.

Comment: Strange. In R, try cutting off the top 383,650 records and export: `df <- tail(df, n=652569-383650)`. Then, try importing to Stata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125906/discussion-between-florian-and-parfait).

Comment: Strange importing the tail woks fine for the first observations but then again stops before the end of the file `(9 vars, 157,855 obs)`

Answer (score 0):

Using Stata 14.2 (14.1 should be the same) ...

```
    import delimited <yourfile>, delimiter(space, collapse) bindquote(strict) colrange(2) encoding(UTF-8) clear

    describe

Contains data
  obs:             6                          
 vars:             8                          
 size:         3,012                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
project_id      byte    %8.0g                 
project_title   str38   %38s                  
project_owner~d str2    %9s                   
comment_user_~d str2    %9s                   
comment_date    str19   %19s                  
comment_censo~d byte    %8.0g                 
censored_reason byte    %8.0g                 
comment_content str438  %438s                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.
```

Comment: Thank you, but there should not be v9 and v1.

Comment: I edited my answer to use colrange() to exclude the first row. Also, the original **describe** output should not have contained v9. In my haste I must have copied the wrong output. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm it crashes with:
`There are more columns than allowed by this Stata. See help maxvar for more information
r(900);` for my big text file, for the small sample provided I end up with having a variable `v8` ?

Comment: My solution was based on what you originally posted in the original code section. I copied and pasted that into a text file and the results are shown. The difference between what you pasted and what is available from your download is the first row where it contains '    "project_id"'. The leading spaces are a delimiter that corresponds to the numbered columns you want to omit. Without the leading spaces the columns are misaligned. The leading spaces have the same effect as having a variable coded in your text file for the row counts. The dialog box can help show this before you import...

Comment: ... As for the r(900), I can only speculate, but there is likely something that is malformed with your text file. You might try importing a range of rows at a time to see if you can get an idea where the problem lies.

Comment: Hmm I think if the text file was malformed I could not import in R without errors - right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just because a program can read and write its own data does not mean that it conforms to a standard. Similarly I can't tell why Stata is trying to create a large number of variables when it reaches a certain row. Perhaps there are unbalanced quotes in the file. The only solution is to inspect the file around the row/rows giving the trouble -- or maybe you could export the file using a delimiter that is likely not in the file, a | for example. In summary you seem to be struggling with 2 issues, the first is a column alignment problem and the second is anomalies in the file.